# Vue ignore custom component tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

On my site I am using Google CSE (custom search engine by google).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  ...
  <gcse:search></gcse:search>
  ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({ el: '#app' })
</script>
```

As you can see, I have a "gcse input" placed inside of my vue application.

Therefore I am getting a warning:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<gcse:search>`

So my question is how it possible to stop attempting to initialize this custom component in Vue.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Ok. And should I worry about this?

Comment: Vue will probably completely break your custom search engine next time it renders.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Vue thinks that you are trying to load a Vue component named `gcse:search`.

In order to ignore this tag, add the [`v-pre` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre):

```
<gcse:search v-pre></gcse:search>
```

---

Or, you could add the `gcse:search` tag to Vue's list of [ignoredElements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements):

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['gcse:search']
```

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to figure out how to get Vue to not render the code in my `<pre><code>` tag which was a part of a documentation site showing example code.

Comment: According to my tests, `v-pre` completely ignores the element, so you can't use anything reactive like `v-bind`. On the other hand, configuring `ignoredElements` makes Vue render the element as it would normally, only without throwing errors about unknown custom element, so you can use reactive datas and all with it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer of [thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678454/thanksd), you can ignore the unknown tags by adding these tags in the ignoredElements property:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['gcse:search']
```

And you can also ignore these tags by using regex instead of using strings:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/gcse:*/]
```

This is very useful if you want to ignore more tags/components with a specific pattern. In this case, you could ignore all tags starting with "gcse"

Comment: Suggestion for regex example: `/^gcse:/`

Answer (score 4):

In *Vue 3* it's different.

There are two ways to configure it.

### 1. If You are using `runtime compiler`

**Note that this will not work if you are using** `runtime-only build`

```js
const app = createApp({})
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('ion-')
```

### 2. Using `runtime-only build`

Here you have to add a rule in `webpack.config.js` for `vue-loader`

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('ion-')
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
]
```

### Extra

if you are using `laravel-mix` the pervious ways will not work for you, the right way is to pass `options` in vue function of `laravel-mix`

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .vue({
 options: {
  compilerOptions: {
   isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('ion-')
  }
 }
})
```

#### References:

1. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#config-ignoredelements-is-now-config-compileroptions-iscustomelement
2. https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-elements-interop.html#_2-x-syntax
3. https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Vite? It seems like trying to set like I did in my question didn't work. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78016346/how-do-i-render-raw-js-customelements-from-external-lib-in-vue-vite)