# Conflict vue in two different Laravel packages

Tags: laravel, vue.js

There are two packages in both packages there are Vue components. I compile everything in packages via webpack.mix. The problem arises when I connect these packages in the framework. The problem is that Vue of package number 1 cannot find component 2 of the package because the component is not registered. In general, what can be the right way when connecting packages, when both packages have vue?

The packages are mine.
In package #1 I have a layout

```
<body id="vue-admin">
  <div id="component">
     <select-component></select-component>
  </div>     
</body>
```

**`<select-component>` is a component of package #2**

**app.js package #1**

```
const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#vue-admin',
    components: {
        'example-component': require ('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default,
        'menu-component': require ('./components/MenuComponent.vue').default,
        'flash-component': require ('./components/FlashComponent.vue').default,
        'image-upload-component': require ('./components/ImageUploadComponent.vue').default,
        'table-component': require ('./ components/TableComponent.vue').default,
    }
});
```

**app.js package #2**

```
const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#component',
    components: {
        'select-component': require ('./components/SelectComponent.vue').default,
    }
});
```

Error: unknown custom element: `<select-component>` - did you register the component correctly? for recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: What packages are you using? Also, please can you explain/show how you're trying to use/connect them.

Comment: I edited the question. In general, I'm starting to think about making one package for the components.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Unregistered components can be ignored.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements,
[Vue ignore custom component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040689/vue-ignore-custom-component-tag)