# Vue standalone component getting Unknown custom element on custom tags

Tags: vue.js

I have a template in a standalone Vue component that is inserted into a liquid file. In order to avoid styling conflicts I've decided to create custom tags, as in my case an iFrame does not work.

These tags ARE NOT components, they are simply replacements for `div` `span` and other standard HTML tags that carry unique styling that I am trying to avoid. Also I've tried `all: unset` and similar CSS hacks to no effect. I need these tags.

However, I'm now getting the following warning:
`Unknown custom element: <freshie-div> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

As these are not components, I'm not real sure how to get rid of this warning. The warning is important to be removed because customers will see the warning and lose their minds.

Here is some of the condensed code:

```
  template: 
`
<freshie-div :style="divStyle">
  <freshie-div :style="buttonContainer" v-if="displayLauncherButton">
    <freshie-button 
      :style="buttonStyle"
      @click="openCreditPanel()"
    >\${ returnLauncherText }</freshie-button>
  </freshie-div>
 `
```

Nothing especially crazy, other than the custom tags.

EDIT:
I am creating my component with `Vue.component('freshie', {` instead of `Vue.createApp({`

And it seems like because of that this isn't working:

```
  components: {
    'freshie-div': 'div',
    'freshie-span': 'span',
    'freshie-button': 'button'
  },
```

I'm getting the following error: `Invalid Component definition: button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vue 3

You could register those components as aliases to the native elements:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: `<freshie/>`
})

app.component('freshie', {
  components: {
    'freshie-div': 'div', 
    'freshie-h1': 'h1', 
    'freshie-button': 'button' 
  },
  template: `<freshie-div>
    <freshie-h1>Hi there</freshie-h1>
    <freshie-button @click="onClick">Click</freshie-button>
  </freshie-div>`,
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      alert('hello world')
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abEMroE?editors=1010)

### Vue 2

In Vue 2, the alias must be done with a `template` option:

```js
Vue.component('freshie', {
  components: {
    'freshie-div': { template: `<div v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs"><slot/></div>` }, 
    'freshie-h1': { template: `<h1 v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs"><slot/></h1>` }, 
    'freshie-button': { template: `<button v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$attrs"><slot/></button>` }, 
  },
  template: `<freshie-div>
    <freshie-h1>Hi there</freshie-h1>
    <freshie-button @click="onClick">Click</freshie-button>
  </freshie-div>`,
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      alert('hello world')
    }
  }
})
  
new Vue({
  template: `<freshie/>`
}).$mount('#app')
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWrxMXx?editors=1010)

Comment: Alternatively, you could avoid these aliases by using a Custom Element with Shadow DOM, which prevents external style effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the v-pre directive to the custom tags as pointed out here: [Vue ignore custom component tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040689/vue-ignore-custom-component-tag)

But be aware that this prevents rendering of all vue elements in the custom tags: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-pre

Unfortunately I see no way to get rid of the warning without using regular tags or real vue components.